# C# hash table of array list is not printing any results

Tags: c#, arrays, hash, hashmap

I am creating an hash table in C# then adding key for it and i am adding array list as values

Then i am tring to print array list which is values but it is not working

```
using System;

namespace text.cs
{
    class Exec
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            Hashtable variations_array = new Hashtable();
            ArrayList item_array = new ArrayList();
            item_array.Add ("one");
            item_array.Add ("two");
            variations_array.Add ("hi", item_array);
            if (variations_array.Contains("one"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This student name is already in the list");
            }

            foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in variations_array)
            {
                //Console.Write (entry.Key);
                string sv = ( entry.Key as string[] )[ 0 ];
                Console.WriteLine("{0}",sv);


            }

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> pair in variations_array)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(pair.Key);
                foreach (string item in pair.Value)
                    Console.WriteLine("\t" + item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have three print statements(Console.Write) but none of them are working?

How to make it work?

Comment: Any reason you're still using the non-generic collections rather than `Dictionary<,>` and `List<>`?

Comment: Fix this line : string sv = (entry.Key as string);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This condition checks for a key with a value `"one"`:

```
variations_array.Contains("one")
```

That doesn't exist - you've added a single entry with a key of `"hi"`. That's why your first `Console.WriteLine` doesn't execute.

Next:

```
string sv = ( entry.Key as string[] )[ 0 ];
Console.WriteLine("{0}",sv);
```

The key isn't a string array - it's a single string. Therefore the `as` operator returns `null`, and you should get a `NullReferenceException`.

Next:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> pair in variations_array)
```

This is performing an implicit cast of the `DictionaryEntry` to `KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>`. That cast will fail. So if your code hadn't thrown an exception due to the previous problem, it would fail here.

It's hard to know how to "fix" this as we're not really clear on what you're trying to achieve, but I'd *strongly* advise you to start using the generic collections (e.g. `List<T>` and `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`) which will make life much simpler:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
dictionary["hi"] = new List<string> { "one", "two" };
foreach (var entry in dictionary)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}", entry.Key);
    Console.WriteLine("Values: {0}", string.Join(", ", entry.Value));
}
```

Comment: instead of this string.Join(", ", entry.Value) how could i get first element of array?

Comment: @Mounarajan: Well `entry.Value` is a `List<string>` - so I suggest you look at the documentation of `List<T>`. If you still have questions about other aspects of what you're trying to do, please ask in a new (specific) post.